# “Areas” vs. “Themes” in the classification of a university’s topics

Tags: terminology

I am applying for a university, and on their website they have divided topics in “Areas” and “Themes”. For example, *Areas* contains *Information Systems* and *Computer Science* and *Themes* contains *Big Data* and *Cybersecurity.*

As the heading says, what is the difference between *areas* and *themes* in this context? In my opinion, there is a great many that overlaps making the margins fuzzy between the terms.

Comment: What's your field?

Comment: Sounds like a a distinction that PR/Marketing people make to underline the interdisciplinarity of the university: while there are distinct "areas" (as in "faculties"), they share "themes" (stuff to work on), so they collaborate in an interdisciplinary way. For example, cybersecurity is a field of research that EE, CS, and sociology people can work on.

Comment: This is division happens in a single faculty.

Comment: I suppose this is more appropriate for English.SE. What do you think, @DCTLib?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I don't know. Maybe, maybe not. I think that jakebeal's answer is good and suggests that the words "areas" and "themes" are used in a very special meaning that seems to be specific to individual universities/department. In that case, it's not so much an question of English.

Answer (score 4):

Many departments will organize themselves internally in multiple various different ways, base on how they've organized their program.  For example, where I went the Electrical Engineering and Computer Science Department was organized in at least the following (partially independent) ways:

- Three different degree tracks (EE, CS, and EECS): which one you chose dictated your graduation requirements.
- Seven focus areas (devices, signal processing, electrodynamics, AI, algorithms, systems, biomedical): these were used in organizing graduation requirements.
- Several major "laboratories" comprising up to 100 faculty or more, which were primarily EECS but also overlapped with other departments: these were the primary organizations of research and graduate life (beyond one's own supervisor, of course)
- A number of "themes" within the focus areas, that were used for determining aspects of Ph.D. qualification.

Other departments are likely to have similar degrees of intricacy, as the result of the evolution of complex negotiations between different people and organizations over many decades.  Moreover, they are likely to use the same words differently, because there are only so many ways to say things like "area" and "theme" and lots of different odd organizational specifics that one might be mapping them to.

In your own case, it sounds like the "areas" are more durable aspects of study, where the "themes" are current hot topics.  The only way to know for certain what they mean to that organization, however, is to read the university's documentation online (if they are well organized) or to contact the people there directly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the department but I guess that:
**Area** is somewhat more stable while **themes** can change more quickly.

For example, big data may be a topic for up to another decade or two but computer science will stay for more than half a century.

Also, I would guess that people from different areas could work together on the same theme. I may also be that the department hires a new guy in some of their present area but this guy will add an additional research theme.

Answer (score 1):

Though it does not seem to be the case in this specific context, a "Theme"-like structure sometimes exists to allow interdisciplinary research and study. Where I am, there is (for example) an environmental-science "theme" that pulls from several life-science departments across two colleges, as well as various social-science departments (for human involvement in the environment).